# What does "case" mean on a museum guide?

Tags: meaning, translation

"First, head to Room 51 on Level 3 and find **Case 4**."

This appears on a guide to visit The British Museum. This guide is designed for children and it is full of activities, pictures and there isn't much information.

I need to translate it into Spanish, but I don't understand the meaning of this term. Is it suppose to mean the "item" you need to find on that room and level in order to understans all the information given in the guide?

I really appreciate your help! Thank you.

Comment: Probably a glass case... _mostrador_. How big is the "item" in question?

Comment: The definition to the word "case' that indicates _display_ falls low on the list of definitions of most online dictionaries. So in this  _case_.... I suggest we be lenient on VTC "for lack of research".

Comment: Google translate gives caso, caja, asunto. "caja" makes the most sense in this context.

Comment: "vitrina" is a better translation into Spanish.

Comment: @Pere Here in Guatemala it's called a _mostrador_... _vitrina_ is a shop window display. It would depend on the size of the item, which I asked for in my first comment.

Comment: @Acccumulation Another example of why not to trust Google Translate...sure _caja_ could also be "case", but that describes something like a guitar case, hence not for display. _Caja_ basically means "box"....also used for cardboard carton, wooden crate, cash register, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a display case.

[image: Glass display case]

They can range in size from relatively small to very large.

Comment: ...but a bad example of an informative description. Asteroids can also range in size from relatively small to very large, but they are not at all the same size as display cases.

Comment: @Tony ... when you find a display case over 1 km across, let me know... In the meantime, perhaps you can give the maximum and minimum sizes. ;)

Comment: @Greybeard I think that was the point: without any dimensions, that sentence doesn't really mean much, and might as well not be there. Perhaps something like "they can range in size from a table-top box less than a metre wide to an enclosure stretching from floor to ceiling and a few metres wide"?

Comment: @IMSoP: yes, exactly. Or "smaller than a cat to bigger than an elephant".

Comment: @TonyK  "smaller than a cat to bigger than an elephant" includes viruses and galaxies

Comment: @TonyK - once the OP knows what "case" in "find Case 4" means, their own intelligence will fit in the dimensions to their mental image. *that sentence doesn't really mean much, and might as well not be there.* that point seems trivial until you realize that the picture is a case of a certain size, but, that to be a display case does not restrict the size or cause another noun to be used.

Comment: One of the comments asked how big the item is, maybe Greybeard felt the need to mention size.

Comment: @IMil: No. A virus can't be bigger than an elephant, and a galaxy can't be smaller than a cat. So neither of them fits my description.

Comment: Size _is_ important...